# Composition of functions involving the range

Tags: functions

Consider the functions f, g

A→ B→ C

A → B = f, B → C = g

Show that R(g ◦ f) = g(R(f)). (where R is the range).

Now I think to show R(g o f) = g(R(f)) start with the definitions. x in R(g o f) if x=g(f(y)) for some y. x in g(R(f)) if x=g(y) for some y in R(f) and show two sets equal by showing that x being in either implies x in the other. I'm just not to sure on how to write this out properly and succinctly. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write properly the things you said
:
$$ x \in Im(g \circ f) \iff \exists y \in A | x=g(f(y)) \iff x \in g(Im(f)). $$